# Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator...?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I avg(time(4)) in the following query:

```
  select top 10 avg(e.Duration) from TimeTable e
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator.

Duration is type time(4) such as:

```
Duration
-------------
00:00:10.0000
```

Comment: TIME represents a point in time. If you're trying to store a duration, store it as an integer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Hi, I can't store it as an int...it's not my database.

Comment: Then you'll need to perform a convert or other date operations every single time. You should tell the database owner that they're paying a hefty price to store a duration using a nice format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', e.Duration )` to convert the time into an integer number of milliseconds.  Use that for your aggregate, then convert the result back, e.g. `Cast( DateAdd( ms, 1234, '00:00:00' ) as Time )`.

Comment: What is `ms` here?

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx?ppud=4), it indicates that the difference between the date/times should be returned in units of milliseconds.

Answer (score 9):

Improving off of HABO answer:

```
select top 10
Cast(DateAdd( ms,avg(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', e.Duration)), '00:00:00' )  as time) as 'avg duration' 
from TimeTable e
```

Answer (score 3):

Addition to HABO's and Rafi's answers.

For my case, I had to cast the value of the DATEDIFF to a bigint because my value grew too large and caused an arithmetic overflow error.

```
CAST(DATEADD( ms,AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF( ms, '00:00:00', ISNULL(e.Duration, '00:00:00')) as bigint)), '00:00:00' )  as TIME) as 'avg_time'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like `time` is an invalid type for the `avg()` method. Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) for a list of valid data types.

Also, it seems like you need a group of values for this, which would negate the need for `top 10` with your current query.