# SQL Query - Average time from datetime field

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm struggling with what I thought would be a simple SQL query. Running SQL Server 2014

I have an SQL table, "Visits":

```
Id | EntryTime | Duration
```

And I want to find the average entry TIME OF DAY between two dates, taking into account all records between those dates.

so if my `EntryTime` field between my dates is:

```
2016-04-28 12:00:00
2016-04-20 10:00:00
2016-04-19 08:00:00
2016-04-17 10:00:00
```

Then the average time returned should just be:

```
10:00:00
```

The date should not be taken into account at all, and it should be returned in string format, or a manner which returns ONLY `10:00:00`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
create table mytimes(
   id int identity,
   mydatetime datetime
)

insert into mytimes (mydatetime) values ('2016-04-28 12:00:00')
insert into mytimes (mydatetime) values ('2016-04-20 10:00:00')
insert into mytimes (mydatetime) values ('2016-04-19 08:00:00')
insert into mytimes (mydatetime) values ('2016-04-17 10:00:00')

SELECT Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(mydatetime as time)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) as Time ) 
from mytimes
-- where mydatetime between XXX and YYY

SELECT convert(varchar(8), Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(mydatetime as time)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) as Time )) 
from mytimes
-- where mydatetime between XXX and YYY
```

**output-1** `10:00:00.0000000` - this is an actual Time type that you can do more with if needed

**output-2** `10:00:00` - this is output as a varchar(8)

*Add your where clause as you see fit*

The steps include

- Casting to a `Time` type from a `DateTime`.
- Using the `AVG` on `Time`, this is not supported by type `Time` so you have to first convert `Time` to milliseconds.
- Converting the milliseconds back to a `Time` type
- To avoid `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int` you can cast the result of `DateAdd` to a `BigInt`. Alternatively you can use `seconds` instead of `milliseconds` in the `DateDiff` function which should work unless your result set is overly large.

SO Sources:

- [T-SQL calculating average time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349586/t-sql-calculating-average-time)
- [How to get Time from DateTime format in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql)
- [Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator…?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11787845/1260204)

Comment: @GibralterTop - The OP did specify the result but never if it should be varchar or type Time. Fair enough though, I added another line with a convert to varchar(8) to show that either/or could be retrieved.

Comment: I get the following error on this "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill - what is the type of your `EntryTime` column? In the complete sample code I provided I do not get any errors. That code uses the same values you provided above but uses the column type DateTime. Maybe your result set is much larger?

Comment: My result set is moderately large. It is a datetime column. These queries are running in a third party data dashboard tool but the error seems to be happening at the destinations SQL Server level

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill - ok, i will try with a larger data set. I did just change it to cast the result of DateAdd to a BIGINT which might fix the problem. Can you give it another go?

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill - just tested and reproduced the issue with a table of my own but the fix I just posted works. If you try again you should have no problems.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for both type outputs as well and the explanations so I can follow!

Comment: Rather than doing the `convert(varchar(8)` I would CAST as time(0).  This is because the convert doesn't round the milliseconds correctly whereas the CAST AS TIME(0) does. So this doesn't round correctly: `SELECT convert(varchar(8), Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(mydatetime as time)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) as Time )) 
from mytimes` whereas this rounds correctly `SELECT Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(mydatetime as time)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) as Time(0) ) 
from mytimes` does

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(SECOND, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CONVERT(TIME, EntryTime ))), 0)) 
FROM Visits
WHERE EntryTime >= @begin AND EntryTime <= @end
```

The idea came from here: [T-SQL calculating average time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349586/t-sql-calculating-average-time)

Comment: This gets the right time, how would I trim the end to not display ms?

Answer (score 0):

Yap, you can use the `Time()` to get this done.

Your query becomes like this (modify accordingly)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Visits WHERE TIME(EntryTime) > '06:00' AND EntryTime < '18:00';
```

Comment: The OP is asking for the average time, not a count of the records. Also I do not believe that `TIME(DateTime)` is a built in function in Sql Server, if so can you reference the documentation?