# Adding two column whose datatype is time shows "Operand data type time is invalid for add operator" error

Tags: java, android, sql-server

select Cast(DateAdd(S, sum(DATEDIFF(S,'00:00:00',Time+Total_Time)),'00:00:00')as Time) from tbl_Appointment where Total_Time='02:00:00' AND Customer_Name='ju'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787845/operand-data-type-time-is-invalid-for-avg-operator)

Comment: can you  please explain  this in detail, so i can get idea how it works,Thanks